# JavaScript-based split testing (a/b testing) in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

We have a WordPress blog; there's a message we'd like to show some of our users. It's dynamically rendered by JS (a sort of a slider). We'd like to split-test two possible designs for this notification, and we're kind of lost on the details.

It seems like existing WordPress testing plugins are only for page content, not for dynamic bits like JavaScript. We did find Genetify but it seems old and unmaintained.

Is there a good, current way to split-test content rendered by JS?

Thanks!